# Materialized view "invalidates" when adding constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I have a materialized view in an Oracle 10.2.0.50 database that looks like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_cis
   NOCACHE
   NOLOGGING
   NOCOMPRESS
   NOPARALLEL
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FORCE
           ON DEMAND
           WITH PRIMARY KEY AS
   SELECT component_id, ctn, visible_tag, facility,
          SYSTEM, elev, parent, room_number,
          remarks, safety_class, seismic, quality_level
     FROM v_cis;
```

Pretty straight forward stuff. After creating this materialized view, it is valid and populated with the data I would expect. I then add a constraint to its table, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE mv_cis
   MODIFY ctn CONSTRAINT chk_cis_ctn_null NOT NULL ENABLE VALIDATE;
```

This works as expected, the table gets a new constraint, and all is good in the world.

However, I then look back at the materialized view and (using Toad for Oracle 12) it shows invalid. Looking in the `user_mviews` table reveals that the `COMPILE_STATE` of it is `NEED_COMPILE` and `STALENESS` is `UNDEFINED`. So I run:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_cis COMPILE;
```

No change. Oddly, refreshing the view still works, but it drives me crazy that it shows invalid, and makes my test plan fail even though everything looks to be in order. So, what am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you try creating a new MV with the same DDL (different name).

Comment: Same thing. Creates fine, shows invalid once I add a constraint.

Comment: Oh, that's a whole other thing. If I try creating the MV "ON PREBUILT TABLE" it gives me an "ORA-12060: shape of prebuilt table does not match definition query" even though the column definitions are a perfect match.

Comment: Can I ask why you dont have a NOT NULL constraint on the base table column, yet you need it in the MV?

Comment: @codenheim: v_cis is a view that queries an external database I don't have control over.

Comment: Why `REFRESH FORCE` when `v_cis` is a view that queries external database? Aren't you always going to do complete refresh and never fast refresh? Just perhaps Oracle gets confused trying to determine if fast refresh is possible or not - we have fast refreshable mviews that turn INVALID as soon as there has been DML to the base table. In your case it cannot really determine that, so maybe try creating the mview using `REFRESH COMPLETE` rather than `FORCE`? (Clutching at straws a bit, I know, but perhaps ;-)

Comment: @KimBergHansen: Tried COMPLETE instead, same thing. Goes invalid and no way to get it back to valid.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino: And it does not go valid after a complete refresh? Our mviews do. If it did, then I could have suggested creating the mview with `build deferred` instead of `immediate`, followed by creating constraint, end the process with complete refresh. That would enable the test plan to decide "success", as a complete refresh (and hence normally turning the mview valid) would be part of the project build. I'm inclined to agree with codenheim it's probably a bug, the problem is how to do a workaround ;-) What does a `describe v_cis` show? Anything different here than your other mviews?

Comment: @KimBergHansen: Nope, it stays invalid even after a complete refresh. Describe v_cis shows what I'd expect. I do definitely expect it's a bug, I've just been unable to generate the right keywords to find any ticket for it, and it seems simple enough that this would definitely be documented by now. Oddly enough, I just tried my "base test case" script that shows the "bug" on a different database (same version) and it is valid. So hell if I know at this point.

Comment: I tried to recreate it on 11g and 10.2.0.4 and couldn't. It must be a bug that happens on a very specific scenario. Could only find a bug that was about COMPILATION_ERROR.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna say bug, and you should check Metalink and/or submit a SR.

Here is 11.2 scenario. Granted it is simplistic. I can try it with your actual DDL if you prefer.

```
SQL> create table base(id integer primary key, name varchar2(100) not null,
  2  description varchar2(400));

Table created.

SQL> desc base
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(400)

SQL> create materialized view mv_base build immediate refresh force on demand
  2  with primary key as
  3  select id, name, description from base
  4  ;

Materialized view created.

SQL> desc mv_base
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(400)

SQL> alter table mv_base modify description constraint chk_not_null not null 
  2  enable validate;

Table altered.

SQL> desc mv_base
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 DESCRIPTION                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(400)
```

Now check if need compile.

```
SQL> select mview_name, compile_state, staleness from user_mviews;

MVIEW_NAME                     COMPILE_STATE       STALENESS
------------------------------ ------------------- -------------------
MV_BASE                        NEEDS_COMPILE       NEEDS_COMPILE

SQL> alter materialized view mv_base compile;

Materialized view altered.

SQL> select mview_name, compile_state, staleness from user_mviews;

MVIEW_NAME                     COMPILE_STATE       STALENESS
------------------------------ ------------------- -------------------
MV_BASE                        VALID               FRESH
```

Comment: I have other views that I am doing basically the same thing to and they don't behave this way, I am not sure exactly what it is about this view in particular that makes it go invalid.

Comment: I agree with you, which is why I think it may be a bug. It would not be the first I've seen with MViews. Ran into several in 9i and 10.1 with Advanced Replication. Of course, like most things Oracle, there is also often a sufficient, non-obvious explanation, but without active metalink access I can't research it more.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino This might be "Compile Makes Materialized View Invalid When Access to Master Table Granted Via Role (Doc ID 781255.1)".  Someone in your organization must have access to My Oracle Support, have them look up the document for you.